# Having issue setting up Procfile for Flask heroku app deployment

Tags: python, heroku, flask, procfile

I'm able to deploy my app to heroku, but if I try to access the given heroku url for my app I get an "app crashed" H10 error in heroku. I think it's because my Procfile isn't setup correctly. Right now my Procfile reads `web: gunicorn main.py`

The Procfile for the example I was following read `web: gunicorn app:app`

All of the files for my app are in the base folder. The only folders in my base folder are `.git` and `__pycache__` folders.

I'm deploying from my command line. I tried using github deployment before and had a different error.